# Combining observables and sorting by date

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have 2 BehaviorSubjects and 2 observables:

```
private payments = new BehaviorSubject(<Payment[]>[]);
payments$: Observable<Payment[]> = this.payments.asObservable();

private purchases = new BehaviorSubject(<Purchase[]>[]);
purchases$: Observable<Purchase[]> = this.purchases.asObservable();
```

That I'd like to access in a service, combine values into 1 array and sort by date.  I was trying to do something like:

```
let transactions = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(this.payments$, this.purchases$).map(([x, y]) => // do sorting )}
```

but it's not working.  I think it has to do with the fact that I need to `subscribe` to the stream in order to get real values.  But, I would like `transactions` to remain in sync with `payments$` and `purchases$` and emit a new value for their combination any time `payments.next(...)` is called or `purchases.next(...)`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is ok (assuming that you will subscribe to stream) but you have used wrong operator because `forkJoin` emits only when both `payments$` and `purchases$` are completed. If you just want emission of pairs all the time (even when streams are not completed) then just use `combineLatest`:

```
const transactions = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  payments$,
  purchases$,
).map(([payments, purchases]) => /* do sorting */);
```

When `payments$` emits then it takes latest value from `purchases$` and emits both as array.
When `purchases$` emits then it takes latest value from `payments$` and emits both as array.

I don't know what is your case but you can also have a look at https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html.

Difference is that:
When `payments$` emits then it waits for `purchases$` to emit and emits both as array.
When `purchases$` emits then it waits for `payments$` to emit and emits both as array.

EDIT: Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/khxkgwf8/

Comment: okay, this sounds good, but I just want 1 array of all values, not just the pair.

Comment: also, my use case involves having a view that has an array of purchases and payments.  As you can imagine purchases and payments are very similar only 1 adds to a final balance, and the other reduces it.

Comment: Ok so both arrays `Payment[]` and `Purchase[]` should be combined into one array and sorted right? Then just:
`.map(([payments, purchases]) => [...payments, ...purchases])` before sorting to concat both arrays.

If you can't use spread operator then use standard concat:
`.map(([payments, purchases]) => payments.concat(purchases))`

Comment: I accepted your answer but in this fiddle it still only emits the last pair, not the entire array.  I want the entire array

Comment: So you want to accumulate values? You haven't mentioned that :) Use `.scan` to achieve that. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zuLnawe/2/

Comment: ahhh that's what I'm talking about.  I've been searching high and low for that.  I guess when I said "combine" I didn't realize how many different ways it could be inferred

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167659/discussion-between-jeremy-thomas-and-krystianpe).